# WinObjC in Macbook

Tags: ios, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, winobjc

The prerequisite to work with BridgeiOS is to have windows 10 and latest visual studio.
Is there a way we can develop it in Macbook?

Comment: The most we will be able to give you is a "yes" or "no". Only the developers can answer the why, or give you an estimate on Mac compatibility.

Comment: If you have a windows 10 virtual machine running on the mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can develop Windows 10 apps on a Mac Book, **but you will need to have Windows installed.** I use a Mac Book pro, and I have **three** ways of running windows:

1) Installed via [Bootcamp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990), which Apple provides

2) Installed via  a virtualized piece of software, [like Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), which allows me to boot into OS X, then into a Windows environment.

3) If you have an Azure subscription, you can create an Azure VM with Visual Studio already installed, and that way you can do development from any machine. [Here is a tutorial on how to do that.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/01/08/azure-virtual-machine-images-for-visual-studio.aspx)

If you need a free Azure account, [you may be eligible for BizSpark.](http://www.davevoyles.com/bizspark-free-software-cloud-services-o/) This can pay for the bill for your Azure VM running Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you need a Mac to build for iOS, you need a Windows Machine to build for Windows (even with the iOS Bridge).
However, unlike with Apple, Microsoft will let you use a virtual machine.

I have a MacBook running Windows via Parallels. There's also a [free version of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) available. So it's definitely possible to build for Windows 10 on a Mac.